# How to iterate and print the list of dictionaries in xls using python

Tags: python, dictionary, xls, xlwt

I want to read  data from database and convert it into list of dictionaries to put it in to a XLS File for reporting.

I tried python code for report since it's easier for me write code with minimum programming knowledge

I want to Write the list of dictionaries within list of dictionaries to an XLS File.

I try to generate the xls file but not getting the result correctly

```
data1 = [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':[{'d':4,'e':5},{'d':8,'e':9}]},{'a':5,'b':3,'c':[{'d':8,'e':7},{'d':1,'e':3}]}]

#Output need to be print like this in excel
A   B    D  E  
1   2
         4   5
         8   9
5   3       
         8   7
         1   3
```

Here is code i tried

```
try:
    import xlwt
except Exception, e:
    raise osv.except_osv(_('User Error'), _('Please Install xlwt Library.!'))
filename = 'Report.xls'
string = 'enquiry'
worksheet = wb.add_sheet(string)
data1 = [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':[{'d':4,'e':5},{'d':8,'e':9}]},{'a':5,'b':3,'c':[{'d':8,'e':7},{'d':1,'e':3}]}]
i=0;j=0;m=0;
if data1:
   columns = sorted(list(data1[0].keys()))
worksheet.write_merge(0, 0, 0, 9, 'Report')
worksheet.write(2,0,"A")
worksheet.write(2,1,"B")
worksheet.write(2,2,"D")
worksheet.write(2,3,"E")
for i, row in enumerate(data1,3):
    for j, col in enumerate(columns):
        if type(row[col]) != list:
            worksheet.write(i+m, j, row[col], other_tstyle1)
        else:
            #if list  then loop and group it in new cell
            if row[col] != []:
                row_columns = sorted(list(row[col][0].keys()))
                for k, row1 in enumerate(row[col],1):
                    for l, col1 in enumerate(row_columns):
                        worksheet.write(k+m+1, l+3, row1[col1])
                        #iteration of m for new row
                        m+=1
                    #m+=1
```

I got output like this

```
A  B   D   E
1  2
       4
           5
       8
           9
5   3
       8
           7
       1
           3
```

Comment: In your data 'C' is a list with some objects. I absolutely have no idea how and by what rules list of objects transofrms into the empty column in the result. From my point of view data for first two rows should be: [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':'', 'd':'', 'e':''}, {'a':'', 'b':'', 'c':'', 'd':4, 'e':5}]

Comment: @m9_psy  question updated

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have

```
m += 1
```

inside your inner for loop.  So, for every element in c, you are putting it down one more row.  (Your commented out line at the end was right.)

By the way, it's better to use meaningful variable names than just letters for variables (e.g. row_offset).

Comment: yes the outer loop is correct but if i use the one like in the comment code m+=1 it throws error that overwriting in worksheet.This is just a sample piece of code used in application

Comment: Well, I think that should be your question - not the one about printing out of line.  But, you will need to add more information about the error.